# MySQL Query Multiple LEFT Joins problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the required result from the following query but it doesnt seem to work...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
u.user_name as user_name,
u.total_points as total_points,
u.user_id as user_id,
COUNT(a.id) as user_total_articles_published,
COUNT(r.id) as user_total_replies_published,
COUNT(v.id) as user_total_votes_done
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN articles as a ON u.user_id=a.user_id
LEFT JOIN replies as r ON u.user_id=r.user_id
LEFT JOIN votes as v ON u.user_id=v.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY u.total_points DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If i remove the last 2 LEFT jOINS the query will work... whats wrong with the other 2? Do i have to use another method for this to work?

thanks

Comment: it doesn't give me the desired result... i mean that user_total_articles_published returns a bigger number than the correct one when i add the other 2 LEFT JOINs... so there must be something wrong with the query..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think by 'not working' you mean that the query returns too many records? That is because of the combination of joins. You return each reply for each article record, so the numbers are multiplied. You can solve this by using `DISTINCT` in the COUNT. That way, you count the unique id's, so you count each article only once:

```
COUNT(distinct a.id) as user_total_articles_published,
COUNT(distinct r.id) as user_total_replies_published,
COUNT(distinct v.id) as user_total_votes_done
```

[edit]

A possibly faster solution, eliminating the need for DISTINCT and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  u.user_name as user_name,
  u.total_points as total_points,
  u.user_id as user_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM articles a 
   WHERE a.user_id = u.user_id) as user_total_articles_published,
  (SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM replies r 
   WHERE r.user_id = u.user_id) as user_total_replies_published,
  (SELECT COUNT(v.id) FROM votes v 
   WHERE v.user_id = u.user_id) as user_total_votes_done
FROM users as u
ORDER BY u.total_points DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: thats correct! thank you... by the way i have added the distinct on top but i didnt know i had to re-add it in each COUNT() ... thats something i learnt.. thank you

Comment: It's bad idea, your temporary table can become extremelly big. It will include product of all records reply and votes tables before grouping.

Comment: The distinct at the top is only to get distinct values in the result. The distinct in the count is to only count distinct values instead of the total number of rows. They have different meanings and can be used together if needed.

Comment: @varela. In other databases I would agree and I would rather use sub selects to get the count. But in my experience with MySQL this method fast. MySQL is optimized for joins and doesn't perform well with most sub selects.

Comment: @GolezTrol MySQL possible to optimize subqueries, but use disctinct to remove result of product is bad idea. Imaging that you have 10K replies and 100 votes for one user.

Comment: I see that it takes a little more than my other pages to load... is there anything wrong with the performance?and if so how can i make it load faster?

Comment: If you got many records, that is possible. I've added another solution. Hope that's better. You should check if you got the right indexes too. At least `user_id` should have an index in all tables.